# Error CS1612 The return value of "Figur.Standort" is not a variable and therefore cannot be changed

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, syntax-error

Hello this is my first question on this page because neither my teacher nor ChatGPT could help me, both said that they dont find an mistake.

I want to make an program that tests if the knight can run over every square on the chessboard without using a sinle square twice.

Now i have the Problem that my IDE (Visual Code Community) gives me the (NET7.0)

Error:
"CS1612"

which says:
"The return value of "Figur.Standort" is not a variable and therefore cannot be changed."

(The Error is in the Method "Bewegen")

```
class program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //Playfield chessboard
        bool[,] Spielfeld = new bool[8, 8]; ;

        //Mögliche Spielzüge des Springers
        Pos[] Spielzüge = new Pos[8];
        Spielzüge[0] = new Pos(1, 2);
        Spielzüge[1] = new Pos(1, -2);
        Spielzüge[2] = new Pos(2, 1);
        Spielzüge[3] = new Pos(2, -1);
        Spielzüge[4] = new Pos(-1, 2);
        Spielzüge[5] = new Pos(-1, -2);
        Spielzüge[6] = new Pos(-2, 1);
        Spielzüge[7] = new Pos(-2, -1);

        //Startposition of the knight on the playfield
        Pos Position = new Pos(1, 0);

        //Knight
        Figur Springer = new Figur(Spielzüge, Position);

        //Mainloop
        while (true)
        {


        }
    }
}
class Figur
{
    public Pos[] Möglichkeiten { get; set; }
    public Pos Standort { get; set; }

    public Figur(Pos[] möglichkeiten, Pos standort)
    {
        Möglichkeiten = möglichkeiten;
        Standort = standort;
    }
    public void Bewegen(int zugIndex)
    {
        Standort.X += Möglichkeiten[zugIndex].X;
        Standort.Y += Möglichkeiten[zugIndex].Y;
    }
}
struct Pos
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public Pos(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

i Expectet that the Method "Bewegen"
uses the in Möglichkeiten[Index] saved Pos to calculate the new "Standort"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pos` is a value type (struct), therefore whenever you access the property `Standort`, you will get a copy and thus are not able to modify the X/Y properties of the original.

Option 1: change to a reference type by replacing `struct Pos` by `class Pos`.

Option 2: assign a new Pos to Standort:

```
Standort = new Pos(Standort.X + Möglichkeiten[zugIndex].X, Standort.Y + Möglichkeiten[zugIndex].Y);
```